# Update Trigger Appends data twice to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

O.F.,

So I have been attempting to build a trigger that will update a table based on the when a a row is updated in a different table. The trigger so far looks like this.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tst_update_USCATVLS_6]
   ON  [dbo].[IV00101]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ITEMNUMBER VARCHAR(75)

    SET @ITEMNUMBER = (SELECT ITEMNMBR FROM dbo.IV00101 WHERE DEX_ROW_TS = (SELECT MAX(DEX_ROW_TS) FROM dbo.IV00101))

    UPDATE dbo.EXT00101 SET STRGA255 = (RTRIM(LTRIM(STRGA255))) + '_0' WHERE PT_UD_KEY = @ITEMNUMBER AND PT_UD_Number = 2
```

What seems to happen when I run the test update like the one below.

```
UPDATE PDM.TEST.dbo.IV00101
        SET USCATVLS_6 = 'OBSOLETE'
WHERE ITEMNMBR = 'HMLGDN-7563252-4'
```

Is that the trigger fires but updates the desired column twice. The end  result being this 20025947756319_0_0 instead of this 20025947756319_0.

The weird part of all of this is if I drop the trigger and run the same test update and then run the update statement that was in the trigger all statements execute and the data is updated as desired.

So running this as one block of code works:

```
UPDATE PDM.TEST.dbo.IV00101
        SET USCATVLS_6 = 'OBSOLETE'
WHERE ITEMNMBR = 'HMLGDN-7563252-4'

DECLARE @ITEMNUMBER VARCHAR(75)

SET @ITEMNUMBER = (SELECT ITEMNMBR FROM PDM.TEST.dbo.IV00101 WHERE DEX_ROW_TS = (SELECT MAX(DEX_ROW_TS) FROM PDM.TEST.dbo.IV00101))

UPDATE PDM.TEST.dbo.EXT00101 SET STRGA255 = (RTRIM(LTRIM(STRGA255))) + '_0' WHERE PT_UD_KEY = @ITEMNUMBER AND PT_UD_Number = 2
```

If any one can help me figure out why this is happening I would greatly appreciate it.

Kindest regards,
Z.

Comment: Your trigger has two MAJOR flaws. First is that you assume that only 1 row will ever be updated. This is not how triggers work in sql server. They fire once per operation, not once per row. The second flaw is that you are not referencing the inserted or deleted virtual tables. In other words, every time you update a row in your table you will also update EVERY row in the table.

Comment: @Sean Lange , Following your advice about referencing the the inserted and deleted table I made another trigger so i could see the data in the two temp tables. When I run the update statement seems write to the insert and delete table twice that is I get back 4 separate data sets 2 for each table. Is that a normal output for a unique item?

Answer (score 0):

Having read Sean Lange's Comments I looked up inserted and deleted tables. I saw reference to these tables before but didn't realize they were temporary tables and thought they were physical tables of the database in the example/answers I saw. Anyway I created a trigger to show the data in each which helped me see how to join them to the update statement in the trigger. All the code is below.

Trigger to see what was in Inserted and Deleted as well as the join referencing the Inserted table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[inserted_deleted_Table]
   ON  [dbo].[IV00101]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

select 'NEW DATA', * from inserted  --new data

select 'OLD Data', * from deleted --old data

select 'iv00101', * From iv00101 as i JOIN inserted as u on i.itemNmbr = u.itemNmbr  and i.DEX_ROW_TS = u.DEX_ROW_TS
    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
```

The end solution was to remove this peice of code:

```
SET @ITEMNUMBER = (SELECT ITEMNMBR FROM INV00101 WHERE DEX_ROW_TS = (SELECT MAX(DEX_ROW_TS) FROM INV00101 ) AND USCATVLS_6 ='OBSOLETE' )
```

And then Add a the FROM clause to the UPDATE Statement:

```
UPDATE PDM.TEST.dbo.EXT00101 SET STRGA255 = (RTRIM(LTRIM(STRGA255))) + '_0' 
    FROM (
            SELECT u.ITEMNMBR ,
                    u.DEX_ROW_TS
            From iv00101 as i JOIN inserted as u on i.itemNmbr = u.itemNmbr  and i.DEX_ROW_TS = u.DEX_ROW_TS) as p 
    WHERE PT_UD_KEY = p.ITEMNMBR AND PT_UD_Number = 2
```

Once I figured out that insert and deleted table were temp tables not actual tables in a DB all the pieces sorta fell into place. Thanks for pointing me in the direction I needed to go @Sean Lange.

Best Regards,
Z.

Comment: Glad that is working for you. Just keep in mind that when you have scalar variables in a trigger is a huge red flag that you need make sure you are allowing for multiple rows. Looks like your new version is going that. Well done and taking some advice and digging in to find a solution!!!